# Application_PostAuthenticateRequest equivalent in OWIN OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

To enable my service layer to access the current User Id anytime it needs, I use Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

The service layer is used by two front-end layers, one MVC App and one MVC Web Api used for a Mobile App.

In the web app, I use Forms Authentication and the Principal is set into `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`. It works fine.

In the web Api, I use Owin. But I cannot find a way to set that Principal after each request is authenticated with the access token.

I can do it when the user logs in with its credentials by overriding `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` into my `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` or when he logs with its refresh token by overriding `GrantRefreshToken` in the same class.

But where could I assign it for requests automatically authenticated with the access token ?

NB. I know that in my Api Controllers I can access the current User, and it is correctly set, but I don't want to pass it with each call to my service layer.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't a static class going to give the same value to all callers?

Comment: Edited the question: the static class only sets Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to set it.

The bearer validation is not done by the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. I had to implement a custom `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`, and override the `ValidateIdentity` method:

```
public class MyBearerAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new Principal(context.Ticket.Identity);
        return base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    }
}
```

And plug that provider into my app by using:

```
OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions bearerAuthenticationOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Provider = new MyBearerAuthenticationProvider()
};
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(bearerAuthenticationOptions);
```

Unfortunately Thread.CurrentPrincipal is null in my Business Layer. I assume the token validation is done in another thread than the request execution. So I'll have to change my method.